# angular forms + bootstrap 'is-invalid', 'is-valid'

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Imagine I have a small form and use reactive approach
For example, I have two inputs

```
...
<input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
<input formControlName="amount" name="amount" type="text" class="form-control">
...
```

I want to track changes and add bootstrap classes 'is-valid'/ 'is-invalid' for appropriate cases.
The problem is that the only way I see I can do it is this:

```
<input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                 [ngClass]="name.invalid && name.touched ? 'is-invalid' : ''">
```

In ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.name = this.shoppingListForm.get('name');
  }
```

Is there a better approach. What is really annoying for me is a lot of "mud" in html.

> So, if form should has default style, it means the page was loaded and
>   input wasn't touched

I found out that I can do this, but still guess there is a better approach. By "better" I mean that won't make html so dirty

```
<input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': name.invalid && name.touched, 
            'is-valid': name.valid, '': name.untouched}"
```

Any help is appreciated)

As @Muhammed stated below, the best way to do what I need is to do it through css

> Just small contribution of mine in case of bootstrap 4.

The problem is that it adds border shadow, so the complete solution for me is this: 
for invalid input

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched{ 
    border-color: rgba(255,10,29,1) !important; box-shadow: none !important; 
}
```

if it is focused, then make border look good

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:focus{ 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255,10,29,0.25) !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to add the any class related to form control state change angular do this by default you just need to add a style related to these classes

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

this class indicate the input control is invalid and toched , this mean you just need to work on the style.

Comment: As @Muhammed stated above, the best way to do what I need is to do it through css
Just small contribution of mine in case of bootstrap 4. The problem is that it adds border shadow, so the complete solution for me is this:
for invalid input
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
  border-color: rgba(255,10,29,1) !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
if it is focused, then make border look good
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255,10,29,0.25) !important;
}

Comment: And what about if I want to use bootstrap styles? I tried to write ```.is-invalid``` and ```.is-valid``` inside SCSS with including ```bootstrap/forms``` and ```bootstrap/mixins```, but my compilator started complaining about much memory consumed...

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple!

You just have to set `[ngClass]` correctly in the template and name the field form with # and ngModel value (ex. `#myfieldname="ngModel"`).
If you use Bootstrap, you can use the `is-valid` and `is-invalid classes`, like this:

```html
<input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
    #myfieldname="ngModel"
    [ngClass]="{'is-valid': myfieldname.touched && myfieldname.valid, 'is-invalid': myfieldname.touched && myfieldname.invalid}">
```

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer. Actually, it is the only good answer here.

Comment: I mean, this is what OP is trying to avoid. The issue is you have to add such a long [ngClass] to all your inputs, just to make bootstrap detect your invalid inputs.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a common method in component:

```js
isValid(field: string) {
    return (!this._form.get(field).valid && this._form.get(field).touched) ? 'is-invalid' : this._form.get(field).touched ? 'is-valid' : '';
}
```

Then in your element refence

```html
[class]="isValid('title')"
```

Comment: Calling functions in templates causes issues with change detection and should be avoided - https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496